# Socket timeout not working Python lora

Tags: python, sockets, lora

I'm noob with python and lora, I want to open a socket wait for a message, if there is no message then do something else, my code so far is:

```
from network import LoRa
import socket
import machine
import time
import binascii
import network

n = 0
try:
   the_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_LORA, socket.SOCK_RAW)
except socket.error:
   exit('Error creating socket.')
the_sock.settimeout(5)
while True:
    try:
        n=n+1
        print("Hola"+str(n))
        time.sleep(1)
        the_sock.setblocking(True)
        ack = the_sock.recv(HEADER_SIZE)
    except socket.timeout, e:
        err = e.args[0]
        print(err)
        break`
```

The problem is that the timeout it's not working, I've checked some answers but the code looks good to me, can you help me please?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You do not need "socket.error" in you except statement, you should just say except. Just a tip, for your "n=n+1" statement you can just do "n+=1." Just helps speed up things I guess. For your "break" statement at the end, there is a mark after it, which could cause an error. Anyway, I hoped I helped in some way! Note: I do not code LORA. I code INET and SOCK_DGRAM, SOCK_STREAM. Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is the timeout, it's not working